# yii2 authclient unknown property: app\models\User::github

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions

I'm using [yii 2 authclient extension](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient)  and [Exemple code here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/blob/master/docs/guide/quick-start.md)

When I login from Facebook following error occurs

> Setting unknown property: app\models\User::github

I can't find function `github()`.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Can you show us, your code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your code, somewhere, you have a code like

- $user->github = ...
- Yii::$app->user->github = ...

and your User class haven't the github property:

`php
class User {
    private $github; // <- I suspect this property is missed
}`

Answer (score 0):

[Exemple code here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/blob/master/docs/guide/quick-start.md) but i don't know property 'github'